# How to give user limited active directory perms?

Tags: permissions, windows-server-2003, active-directory

We are a very small company, and for some time I've been the only guy managing our domain/Active Directory.  I'm NOT a sys admin, I'm a software dev, but I've done the best I could for them.

We're at the place now where we have a Jr IT Associate on board, and I'd like to hand off some of the Active Directory tasks to him, but don't want him to have 'God' permissions.  He **shouldn't** have permissions to create/delete/edit DOMAIN ADMIN level accounts, but I'd like him to be able to create/delete/edit DOMAIN USER level accounts.

Is this doable?

Please let me know if I can help make the question clearer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, create a security group called "Account Creators" or something like that.

In the ADUC console, right click on the OU that you want the user to be able to create accounts in. Click Delegate Permissions. There's is a pre-defined role for creating/deleting accounts. Select it and choose to delegate it to the group that you just made. Then, add whatever users you'd like to it.

Comment: There's also already an Account Operators group with the ability to manage other user accounts that are not also account operators or higher.

Comment: If one wanted more fine-grained permissions, it'd also be an idea to do this with the NTFS permissions on the object in AD and select exactly the operations said group should have access to.

Comment: @RyanRies But then people end up scratching their head when the AdminSDHolder kicks in and some accounts aren't respecting a different delegation 6 months down the line :)

Comment: I'm rarely in this world, so restating to make sure I understand: 1) I create an 'account creators' SG, add JrItGuy user to that.  2) in ADUC, right click on DOMAIN USERS, then 'delegate permissions', then choose role for creating/deleting.  I select and delegate to 'account creators' group.  Does that sound correct?  If I do that, will JrItGuy be denied edit/create/etc for DOMAIN ADMINS?

Comment: MDMarra - my ignorance is showing, but I'm pretty sure that's the default group that all newly created users have always been placed in. We've not organized them further, other than to place a very select few also in the DOMAIN ADMINS group.

Comment: Domain Users and Domain Admins are groups. This process has nothing to do with them. You delegate permission based on OU. Once the account is created, the `JrltGuy` shouldn't have any permission to add people to the privileged Domain Admin group unless you specifically delegate the ability for him to also add users to groups. By default, all new user accounts are members of the Domain Users group. Other than that, they will not be a member of anything.

Comment: So, to answer your question above, No you do not click on "Domain Users" You click on an Organizational Unit and select "Delegate Permission" `JrltGuy` will then be able to create users in that Organizational Unit and all child OUs that inherit permissions from the parent (which should be all of them by default)

Comment: 'Domain Users' group is what I meant, sorry if the all caps made that confusing.

Comment: Thanks MDMarra - I'm going to have to do some research into OU, because I'm obviously clueless there.

Comment: An OU is just the "folder" looking thing in the ADUC console. It's a container for other objects. But yeah, it's definitely a good idea to do some basic reading before you start delegating, sometimes it's a lot easier to just get it right the first time than to try and undo something and re-do it.

Comment: This worked perfectly.  I had to do a bit of organizing and place users into OU's, but then the permissions worked as you suggested.  Cheers.